# Cytoscape Nodes Dynamically Created by SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, graph, cytoscape.js

I'm using a mysql database and I'm trying to create a network graph like a brainstorm chart..... I'm yet to find any examples of Cytoscape Nodes dynamically being created by SQL Query or any other code libary like Cytoscape or neo4j that can do it . I have tried converting it to json first but there is also little documentation on how that works so I'm rather stuck... if there is anything anyone can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON spec is clearly documented: http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json

Wherever your data is coming from, simply convert it to this format.

Beyond that, I can't offer any help because your question is unclear.  Maybe you need some more background information about how databases and webservers work: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=databases+web+servers&t=ffab&ia=web